# How to set App name for apk from Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to set application name for apk as below because gradle by default name it has app-release.apk

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.name.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 20
        versionName "1.1"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName","${appname}")
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

below

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName","${appname}")
```

and

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName","$applicationId".substring(2,"$applicationId".length()-7))
```

But i cant get the excepted result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all{
        def SEP = "_"
        def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
        def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
        def newApkName = flavor + SEP + buildType + ".apk"
        outputFileName = newApkName
    }
}
```

You can add whatever you want to instead of flavor, buildType and SEP. That one is just as an example.

Comment: It throws null value for *variant.productFlavors[0].name* .And im not using productFlavor becoz i need only one apk file. which i already included my *applicationId* in *defaultConfig*

Comment: apkName and applicationId are absolutely different things. Can you try to remove getting of productFlavor then if you are not using them? 

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all{
        def newApkName = defaultConfig.applicationId + ".apk"
        outputFileName = newApkName
    }
}